# I am having problem reversing doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am learning linked lists and was doing a question which asks you to reverse a doubly linked list. My code works perfectly fine but I don't understand how. You can ignore whole thing except the `reverse_list` function. As you can see, in the `while` loop the condition is `ptr->next != NULL`. This condition shouldn't let me reach the last node until the very end operation `ptr = ptr->prev`, which means no other operation inside that `while` loop should be performed in the last node.

By that logic `ptr->prev` must be still pointing to 2nd last node (or you can say 2nd node after reversing) when it should be `NULL`. I don't understand why even though it isn't properly reversed, it gives correct answer.

```
// reverse a double linked list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    struct node *prev;
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} st;

void print(st *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void add_node(st *head, int data)
{
    st *ptr = malloc(sizeof(st));
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    while (head->next)
    {
        head = head->next;
    }
    head->next = ptr;
}

st *reverse_list(st *head)
{
    st *ptr = head->next;
    head->next = NULL;
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        head->prev = ptr;
        ptr->prev  =ptr->next;
        ptr->next = head;
        head = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->prev;
    }
    ptr->next = head;;
    head = ptr;
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    st *head = malloc(sizeof(st));
    head->prev = NULL;
    head->data = 12;
    head->next = NULL;

    add_node(head, 22);
    add_node(head, 1);
    add_node(head, 24);
    add_node(head, 45);

    printf("before reverse\n");
    print(head);

    head = reverse_list(head);
    printf("\nafter reverse\n");
    print(head);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// here is the output

before reverse
12 22 1 24 45 
after reverse
45 24 1 22 12
```

Comment: Which debugger do you have access to? Can you step through the code in your debugger to see how the values update on each iteration?

Comment: OT: In the real world, "reversing a double linked list" makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `void add_node(st *head, int data)` does not properly construct a doubly linked list: it should take a pointer to the `head` pointer in the caller's scope, special case the first node, and set `ptr->next` to point to the previous node in the list.
- `reverse_list` has undefined behavior if the list is empty (`head == NULL`) or if it has a single element (`head->next == NULL`).
- the `print` function iterates along the `next` pointers, but it does not check that the `prev` pointers are correct. The program produces the expected output for the simple 4 element test case, but the `prev` links are incorrect in both the constructed list and its reversed version.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
    int data;
} st;

void print(const char *msg, const st *head) {
    printf("%s", msg);
    while (head) {
        printf(" %d", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

st *add_node(st **headp, int data) {
    st *ptr = malloc(sizeof(st));
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->prev = NULL;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (*headp == NULL) {
        return *headp = ptr;
    } else {
        st *last = *headp;
        while (last->next) {
            last = last->next;
        }
        ptr->prev = last;
        return last->next = ptr;
    }
}

st *reverse_list(st *head) {
    // iterate on the list, swapping the next and prev links
    for (st *node = head; node; node = node->prev) {
        st *next = node->next;
        node->next = node->prev;
        node->prev = next;
        head = node;
    }
    return head;
}

void free_list(st **headp) {
    for (st *node = *headp; node;) {
        st *next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
    *headp = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    st *head = NULL;

    add_node(&head, 12);
    add_node(&head, 22);
    add_node(&head, 1);
    add_node(&head, 24);
    add_node(&head, 45);

    print("before reverse: ", head);
    head = reverse_list(head);
    print("after reverse:  ", head);

    free_list(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
before reverse:  12 22 1 24 45
after reverse:   45 24 1 22 12
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a few questions.
In `add_node` function what was the need of doing `if( ptr==NULL`  check? Could there ever be a situation where ptr becomes NULL?
I am confused as to what `return last = last->next;` is doing. Head is already a double pointer. Any change made in head in `add_node` function will be reflected to head in `main` function. So why you made `add_node` a `st` type instead of making it a `void` type? What is `return last->next=ptr;` actually returning?

Comment: @Adityasingh: `ptr` may be null if `malloc()` fails, which should be tested and handled gracefully.  `return last = last->next;` is equivalent to `last = last->next;` followed by `return last;` combined as a single statement. Same for `return last->next = ptr;`  I changed the `add_node` return type to allow the caller to test for failure: it returns a pointer to the newly allocated node and `NULL` if this allocation failed.  This potential failure is ignored in the test code in `main` but a richer application should test for errors more systematically.